# Is it okay to ask about terminology on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, rules

If I know about something, but don't know it's name -- or if it even has a name -- but it is related to development, would it be okay to ask on Stack Overflow? Or would this be off-topic and not allowed?

Ex: I have one server with multiple websites on it: does this type of server, or group of websites have a name?

Comment: eh, i wouldn't do it. Probably best to ask that in chat, if anywhere.

Comment: *"I have one server with multiple websites on it: does this type of server, or group of websites have a name?"* This would be off-topic for Stack Overflow anyway, as server administration and/or website hosting are not programming-related within the scope defined by our Help Center.